# How do I compile 32bit Perl on a 64bit Linux machine using perlbrew?

Tags: perl, 64-bit, 32-bit, perlbrew

I'm barely familiar with perlbrew. I think I need to use --sitecustomize $filename but I can't find examples of this file anywhere. I have no idea what to put in the file. Anyone got a sample I can look at?

Comment: Same problem here, failed for both 5.12.4 and 5.14.2. I set `export CC="gcc -m32"` as [suggested by Jonathan Leffler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/216090/269126) but to no avail, the variable wasn't picked up by the perlbrew build machinery.

Answer (score 5):

This appeared to work for me, on Centos 5.6 and Centos 6.2 (both 64-bit):

```
$ perlbrew install 5.8.9 -Accflags="-m32 -march=i686" -Aldflags="-m32 -march=i686" -Alddlflags="-shared -m32 -march=i686"
```

Tested with 5.8.9 and 5.12.4.

Caveat: perl still recorded archname=x86_64-linux, and used that for the arch-specific directories in the compiled-in @INC.  This is a wart, but the contents are 32-bit.

Comment: Use the -Darchname=<something> option to Configure to set the arch specific directory e.g. perlbrew install 5.8.9 -Darchname=i686-linux -Accflags="-m32 -march=i686" -Aldflags="-m32 -march=i686" -Alddlflags="-shared -m32 -march=i686"

Answer (score 1):

There's an introductory article on perlbrew website for using sitecustomize file http://perlbrew.pl/Install-a-sitecustomize.pl-file-with-perlbrew.html

However I don't think this file is related to building a 32bit perl on 64bit system. In fact, it does not seem to be possible at the moment, quoting the INSTALL file:

> Natively 64-bit systems need neither -Duse64bitint nor -Duse64bitall.
>   On these systems, it might be the default compilation mode, and there
>   is currently no guarantee that passing no use64bitall option to the
>   Configure process will build a 32bit perl. Implementing -Duse32bit*
>   options is planned for a future release of perl.