# gcc error - ld: fatal: file shmonitor.o wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: c, makefile

While creating executable from some object files from gcc. Getting error as :

```
ld: fatal: file shmonitor.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file sharemem.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file shmaccess.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file shminit.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file shmlock.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `shmonitor'
```

The target is expected to be excutable 'shmonitor'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcc error: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216000/gcc-error-wrong-elf-class-elfclass64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of mismatch of 64 bit or 32 bit OS/Executable/object files. Add flag "-m64" or "-q64" as per OS requirement.