# Error when using .so: "wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64" on 32-bit machine

Tags: python, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

Using Python 2.7.15 Ubuntu 18.04.2 on a 64-bit machine to build per instructions at 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/doc/python-devbox-setup.md#build-the-azure-iot-hub-sdks-for-python-on-linux, we get this error when running the resultant .so on a 32-bit Yocto machine running Python 2.7.12.

Per this post: [gcc error: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216000/gcc-error-wrong-elf-class-elfclass64?rq=1), I imagine the build can be done with a GCC flag.  Simply using "-m32" when running ./build.sh, however, did not work.

I suspect I could also use/change some sort of configuration parameter.  However, I can not find anything obvious to change in the SDK.

More specifically, the error is:
'ImportError: /home/root/build_folder/iothub_client.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you should be cross compiling the Python SDK for your target machine. The -m32 flag according to gcc docs is for Nvidia PTX Options. I suspect you don't want that. You need to find an appropriate tool chain for your target device's architecture and use that to build the Python binary. There is documentation that will help you with this here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/doc/Example%20of%20Cross%20Compiling%20the%20Azure%20IoT%20SDK%20for%20Python.md.

You didn't mention what the architecture of your Yocto device is.

Comment: Mark is, of course, correct.  The -m32 flag had nothing to do with the problem which was really caused by not cross-compiling.  Azure has released an entirely new [IoT SDK for Python](https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-sdk-python) which allows for skipping all of that and writing in pure Python.

Comment: Indeed they have. In the spirit of full disclosure, I work in developer support for Azure IoT technologies but I couldn't tell you about that when I responded because it was not yet deemed public information. I believe this code is still only beta but should make life a lot easier for Python programmers.