# ld: fatal: file bcPACplacebo.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: c++, makefile, solaris, cc

Below are my environments that I am running my project which has C and CPP codes.

uname -a:

SunOS nzdrb12z 5.11 11.4.40.107.3 sun4v sparc sun4v non-global-zone

cc -V:

cc: Studio 12.6 Sun C 5.15 SunOS_sparc 2017/05/30

Currently facing following errors,

```
CURRENT ERROR:

ld: fatal: file /opt/developerstudio12.6/OracleDeveloperStudio12.6-solaris-sparc-bin/developerstudio12.6/lib/compilers/sparcv9/libCCexcept.so.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file bcPLogon.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file bcSecurity.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file bcPAccessCheck.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file bcPEncryption.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file bcPAuthentication.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file bcPSecurityObjects.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: file bcPCEnc.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS6
```

Earlier to this I was facing an error similar to this as mentioned below,

```
ld: fatal: file bcPACplacebo.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

So I did the changes in makefile as below,

1. under MakeDefaults.Solaris64 (Main makefile)

   CC_MEMORY_MODEL_64=-m64

   CC_MEMORY_MODEL_32=-m32

   COMPILEFLAGS=-c -DSOLARIS $(CC_MEMORY_MODEL_64) $(COMMONFLAGS) $(ROGUEFLAGS) -D_REENTRANT $(CC_OPTIONAL_FLAGS) -xO3 -xbuiltin=%all -xlibmil -errtags -erroff nonpodvarargw -mt -std=c++14

   C_FLAGS=-c -DSOLARIS $(CC_MEMORY_MODEL_32) $(COMMONFLAGS) $(ROGUEFLAGS) -D_REENTRANT $(CC_OPTIONAL_FLAGS) -xO3 -xbuiltin=%all -xlibmil -errtags -erroff nonpodvarargw -mt
2. under security module which has few c files (namely bcPACplacebo.c) I did the below changes in the makefile

   bcPACplacebo.o: bcPACplacebo.c

   ```
    cc $(C_FLAGS) -D_HPUX -DCHECK_PASSWORD bcPACplacebo.c -c -o bcPACplacebo.o
   ```

After compiling I started facing the CURRENT ERROR:, I was not expecting that there could be many objects which I may have to differentiate between 64 and 32.

Questions:
I understand this could be the duplicate, but I didn't find working answers from all the threads. But here are my questions,

1. How to resolve this wrong ELF class errors once for all.
2. As I am novice in makefile scripts, I am not much aware of how to tag the objects as 32 and 64. or is there any better method to resolve this.
   Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I remove step1 and 2 changes in the makefile, I still face error      ld: fatal: file bcPACplacebo.o: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32.

Comment: Did you run `make clean` and verify it removed **all** the compiled binaries?

Comment: Yes it did remove all the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix 32-bit & 64-bit objects when compiling - the program has to be either all of one or all of the other - either use -m32 in all commands or -m64 in all commands.